# python 3.10 soap.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True) NoneType Error

Tags: gettext, nonetype

```
soap.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)

Output: 'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'get_text'.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot to go off since you didn't provide a lot of information, but from the information I got, you've put `soap.find` instead of `soup.find`
You could try something like this to fix it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "Your url"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": '(search My user agent)'}


def product_title():
    req = requests.Session()
    page = req.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    productTitle = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)

    print(product)


productTitle()
```